# Is there any method possible to apply LUT(1D or 3D) color effects on html video/image tag using css filter (filter: url(#custom filter)) property?

Tags: html, css, svg, filter, webgl

I am looking for a way by which I can use **SVG** to apply a **LUT(1D and 3D)** on **video/image tag in html** using css **filter: url(#custom filter).**

I have tried the following method as of now:
To apply following 1D LUT:

```
LUT_1D_SIZE 3
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.7 0.7 0.7
1.0 1.0 1.0
```

I copied R-channel column values and put it in table values of feFuncR. Similar for G and B-channel

I wrote this svg filter and called it on video tag in css using "filter : url(#1DLUT)"

```
<filter id="1DLUT" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="componentTransfer">
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.0 0.7 1.0"/>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.0 0.7 1.0"/>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.0 0.7 1.0"/>
        <feFuncA type="identity"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

I got some good results but I am not sure if this is the correct method. Although I compared by importing and applying same LUT on same photo in photoshop. Photos were **almost** similar but i could see some differences.

I tried to apply following 3D LUT:

```
LUT_3D_SIZE 2
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 0.75 0
1 0.75 0
0 0.25 1
1 0.25 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

by same method as above and called it on video/image tag in css using "filter : url(#3DLUT)"

```
<filter id="3DLUT" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
    <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="componentTransfer">
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1"/>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0 0.75 0.75 0.25 0.25 1 1"/>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1"/>
        <feFuncA type="identity"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

But the results were not good (I compared in photoshop and differences were clearly visible) and I am pretty sure this isn't the correct way to apply 3D LUT.

Can anyone suggest any changes in above method or suggest any other method using SVG (or any other alternative) to apply 1D and 3D LUT on html video/image tag ?

Comment: you can combine [playing a video in three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/VideoTexture) with [this](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing-3dlut.html)

Comment: I looked at the approach suggested by you @gman. However this involves copying video frame by frame on canvas and then applying any color effect. I could see some lag in the high quality video whereas CSS filters are totally lag free since they dont involve copying on canvas. So i wanted to go ahead with CSS method only. Could you suggest any way of using custom shaders in CSS. Till 2014, there was one method by which we can use them but it was removed by browsers. Now I cant find any alternative to apply custom shaders in CSS. Could you suggest any alternative to use CSS custom shaders?

Comment: There was never a shipping method of using shaders in CSS. There was a proposal. It was rejected.